# How to calculate how much data will be processed by bigquery listTableData() call?

Tags: java, google-bigquery

There is a possibility to calculate how much data will be processed by a query (uses `getQueryResults` RPC to read rows of the results):

```
BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
QueryJobConfiguration queryConfig =
QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(query).setDryRun(true).setUseQueryCache(false).build();
Job job = bigquery.create(JobInfo.of(queryConfig));
JobStatistics.QueryStatistics statistics = job.getStatistics();
System.out.println(
          "Query dry run performed successfully." + statistics.getTotalBytesProcessed());
```

But there is nothing similar to `getStatistics` when using `listTableData` (uses `tabledata.list` RPC )

```
final TableResult schemaQuery = bigquery.query(newBuilder(query).build());
final TableId tableId = TableId.of(table.datasetId(), table.tableId());
final TableResult tableResult = bigquery.listTableData(tableId, schemaQuery.getSchema(), pageToken(token), pageSize(batchSize));
```

How to calculate how much data will be or was processed by `bigquery.listTableData()` call?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, this has been a use case in one of my personal projects. I think you can estimate the amount of data processed by listTableData by tracking the number of rows retrieved and the size of the rows retrieved. I vaguely remember doing something similar, which in your case would be to:

> 1. Determine the approximate size of each row in the target table.
> 2. Keep track of the number of rows retrieved by the listTableData
>    method.
> 3. Multiply the estimated row size by the number of rows retrieved to
>    estimate the data processed.

```
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.*;

BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
TableId tableId = TableId.of("your_project_id", "your_dataset_id", "your_table_id");

// Step 1: Estimate the size of each row in the table
Table table = bigquery.getTable(tableId);
TableDefinition tableDefinition = table.getDefinition();
Schema schema = tableDefinition.getSchema();
long estimatedRowSize = 0; // Start with a reasonable default value

for (Field field: schema.getFields()) {
  Schema.Type fieldType = field.getType();
  // Adjust the estimatedRowSize based on the data type and complexity of each field
  switch (fieldType) {
  case STRING:
    estimatedRowSize += 64; // Adjust this based on your data
    break;
  case INTEGER:
    estimatedRowSize += 8; // Adjust this based on your data
    break;
    // Add cases for other data types as needed
  }
}

// Step 2: Keep track of the number of rows retrieved by listTableData
int totalRowsProcessed = 0;

// Step 3: Estimate the data processed
Page < TokenResult > pages = bigquery.listTableData(tableId);
for (TokenResult page: pages.iterateAll()) {
  totalRowsProcessed += page.getValues().size();
}

long estimatedDataProcessed = estimatedRowSize * totalRowsProcessed;
System.out.println("Estimated data processed: " + estimatedDataProcessed + " bytes");
```

However Denis, this estimation is approximate, and we should consider data compression and other optimizations during the actual data processing.

You might have to adjust the estimatedRowSize value and calculations based on your specific data and requirements.

Comment: thank you. i'm figuring out how to make it as accurate as possible. i’m surprised why Google didn't provide any support for this